# VirtualBox Kernal issue, rleated to Ubuntu Pro?

Tags: 22.04, virtualbox, ubuntu-pro

I have kind of a new `Ubuntu 22.04` and `VirtualBox` was working fine. I had `Ubuntu Pro` for this machine before, so activated it recently. But after one update, around a week back VMs stopped launching. It was asking to reinstall `virtualbox-dkms` package and then reinstall kernel using `modprob ..` . So I completely removed VirtualBox using

```
sudo apt remove virtualbox*
```

The installed a freshly downloaded deb, the same issue happens when I try to launch my VMs, both `Windows 1`1 and `Ubuntu`. So I took the suggested procedure, `sudo apt remove virtualbox-dkms` and then `sudo apt install virtualbox-dkms`, then the `modprob..` command suggested by VirtualBox.

I kind of tried different variants of the above procedure of removing and installing 3-4 times without success. And got the same error to install dkms and kernel. Is there any chance I can use VirtualBox with `Ubuntu Pro` running? Or is it a lost cause as the Kernel changes might happen more ( suggested by someone on a Discord channel)? Thanks.

Comment: Please edit your question and provide the actual inputs and outputs of the commands you are using (copy and paste, not screenshots). Vague verbal descriptions of what happened are next to useless (this sentence makes no sense at all "The installed a freshly downloaded deb, the same issue happens when I try to launch my VMs, both Windows 11 and Ubuntu."). I can't think of any interaction at all between Pro and VB.

Comment: Hi, I have added everything I have done so far. As for the above sentence I went to VirtualBox website, downloaded the latest deb today morning, installed it through Software app, tried launching my Windows 11 and Ubuntu VMs, but VirtualBox says reinstall virtualbox-dkms packages and run modprob command. I just tried to install VirtualBox again to give you full details. Looks like there is no error this time. I will try some VMs and update. OMG Ubuntu has some mention about latest kernel for 22.04. And my VirtualBox broke after moving to Pro and applying an update. Hence the reference.

Comment: None of your question makes any sense.  You haven't added any versions of any application that you have tried to install.  Recently, Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS with HWE enabled has upgraded the Kernel version to 6.5.0-14-generic where the VirtualBox 6.1 and the virtualbox-dkms are not compatible.  If you boot back to a previous Kernel like 6.2.0-39-generic the 6.1 versions of VirtualBox should work fine.  I have been running VirtualBox 7.0 and I have not had the need to install the virtualbox-dkms and it worked without issue after the Kernel upgrade.

Comment: VirtualBox is in Ubuntu, why download debs from a web site? Those are almost certain to get out of kilter with the rest of your system and eventually break things. What is wrong with `sudo apt install virtualbox`?

Comment: Hi @rusty thanks. That's the exact thing that happened to me. But I didn't knowingly update kernel. Perhaps my choice of uninstalling everything and using the latest deb from VirtualBox ( which happens to be VirtualBox 7 ) helped solve the issue.